# Node mailer Cannot create property 'mailer' on string on Nest JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nodemailer

i newbie in Nest JS. I have to  fix a project using Nest JS. But, when i compiled Nest JS use

```
npm run start:dev
```

i got some error

> [Nest] 19688   - 07/23/2020, 09:26:35   [ExceptionHandler] Cannot
> create property 'mailer' on string
> 'undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined' +16ms TypeError: Cannot
> create property 'mailer' on string
> 'undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined'
> at new Mail (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source code\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer\index.js:45:33)
> at Object.module.exports.createTransport (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source
> code\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\nodemailer.js:58:14)
> at new MailerService (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source code\backend\node_modules@nest-modules\mailer\lib\mailer.service.ts:24:24)
>
> ```
> at Injector.instantiateClass (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source code\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:288:19)   
>
> at callback (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source code\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:75:41)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source
> ```
>
> code\backend\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:116:24)
> at Injector.loadInstance (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source
> code\backend\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:79:9)
> at Injector.loadProvider (D:\MIP\PROJECT\Makmur Jaya\source code\backend\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:36:9)
> at async Promise.all (index 4)

so please help me because i confuse. How can i fix a problem while i can't start server.
thank you guys

Comment: To know what's going on, besides the error, you're going to need to show the configuration you're using for the `MailerModule`. Looks like the connection string is getting set to `undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined`, so I'm guess it's a config issue.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel hmm maybe it's config. okay i will check. thank you for advice